# Characteristic polynomial for an operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial

For a fix matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$. Let the operator $L\colon M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K}) \to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ defined by $L(X)=AX$.

I want to find the characteristic polynomial for $L$ in terms of characteristic polynomial of $A$.

How do I proceed?

Comment: How do you define characteristic polynomial of an operator? Can you apply the definition to your case?

Comment: @gt6989b the characteristic polynomial is defined by $\det(tI_n-A)$

Comment: As a first step, I suggest that you try to find the matrix of $L$ for the $2 \times 2$ case relative to the basis 
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}, \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$
of $M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb K)$. Perhaps you can guess how this pattern would generalize.

Comment: The matrix of $L$ is $A\otimes I_n$, where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). The characteristic polynomial is then $p_{L_A}(r)=\det(A\otimes I_n-rI_{n^2})$. Note that if $Q$ is invertible, then $L_Q(X)=QX$ is invertible. So $L_Q^{-1}L_AL_Q(X)=Q^{-1}AQX$ has the same characteristic as $L_A$. Let's compute the case in which $A=D$ is diagonal. In this case $D\otimes I_n$ has the elements of the diagonal of $D$ repeated $n$ times. So $p_{L_D}=p_D^n$. Therefore $p_{L_A}=p_A^n$ for diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: Next apply that diagonalizable matrices are dense.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks, with your suggestion I can find that the matrix for the operator $L$ is a diagonal block matrix such that the entries in the diagonal are the matrix $A$.

Comment: @JRicardoMunozG That's right, and this matches up with the result of plop's more recent comment regarding the Kronecker product.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Can you suggest any bibliography to study the Kronecker product?

Comment: @JRicardoMunozG One reference I like is Rajendra Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*; he discusses the properties of the Kronecker product in a section of the first chapter.

Answer (score 0):

*Hints.* Let $V_j$ be the subspace of all matrices of which all columns except perhaps the $j$-th ones are zero.

1. Since each $V_j$ is an invariant subspace of $L$ and $V$ is the direct sum of all $V_j$s, we have $p_L=p_{L|_{V_1}}p_{L|_{V_2}}\cdots p_{L|_{V_n}}$, where $p_L$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $L$ and likewise for each $p_{L|_{V_n}}$.
2. Observe that the extraction $\theta_j:V_j\to \mathbb K^n$ defined by $\pmatrix{0&\cdots&0&x&0&\cdots&0}\mapsto x$
   is an isomorphism. Therefore the two linear operators $L|_{V_j}:V_j\to V_j$ and $(\theta_j\circ L|_{V_j}\circ\theta_j^{-1}):\mathbb K^n\to\mathbb K^n$ have the same characteristic polynomials. What is the relationship between $\theta_j\circ L|_{V_j}\circ\theta_j^{-1}$ and $A$?